# Bootstrap tooltips won't hide in newest Safari 8.0

Tags: macos, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, safari8

I have this weird case with Bootstrap tooltips (only) on newest Safari 8.0.
I have a form and I must show a tooltip on each of the inputs (please, don't ask why).

Here is a jsfiddle example

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/d61yuy8q/11/`
```

And here is how it looks in Safari 8.0

[image]

First I thought that our css may cause some issues, so I've stripped it down to pure bootstrap classes. Then I thought maybe I should move those tooltips from inputs to divs that were wrapping inputs but that also didn't help.

At the end I've removed all wrappers and left only the inputs but that also didn't help.

My wild guess is that the new Safari doesn't recognize the mouseleave action if 2 same elements have no space between them.

Does anyone could think of any workaround for that?

Comment: Post this as a browser bug here:  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues /From what I can see the only way is to put vertical space between the inputs, it's a very strange thing. As a work around, you can try to use left or right on the tooltip

Comment: Hey Christiana,
I will definitely do that!  Just wanted to find a good workaround here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by adding a manual trigger (like @play2web is using for popovers) and removing any tooltips before showing a new one as follows:

```
var showTooltip = function() {
    $('.tooltip').remove(); // This line removes any currently showing tootltips
    $(this).tooltip('show');
};
var hideTooltip = function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
};
$("[data-rel='tooltip']").tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
}).focus(showTooltip).hover(showTooltip, hideTooltip);
```

The downside is that you can't use the `delay` functionality anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I personally dont like boostrap tooltip, i have created custom script to replace tootlip with popover, here is how to use it

```
<a href="#" title="This is link">Hello</a>

  $(function() {
      $('[title]').attr("data-rel", "tooltip");
      $("[data-rel='tooltip']")
          .attr("data-placement", "top")
          .attr("data-content", function() {
              return $(this).attr("title")
          })
          .removeAttr('title');


      var showPopover = function() {
          $(this).popover('show');
      };
      var hidePopover = function() {
          $(this).popover('hide');
      };
      $("[data-rel='tooltip']").popover({
          trigger: 'manual'
      }).click(showPopover).hover(showPopover, hidePopover);

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the result is the same in Safari 8.0 – popovers don't hide on mouseleave.

Comment: Have you tried it to use like this <input name="license" type="text" placeholder="Set licensing..." title="License">

Comment: Hey, yes I've tried that and still popovers behave the same as tooltips – they stay visible.

Comment: maybe add $(this).popover().remove();